# Inserção no fim de uma TAD Lista

Tags: c

Olá gostaria de saber o que inserir no condicional para que a mesma ocorra a inserção dos dados no
final da lista, e não no início.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
typedef struct elemento{
int info;
struct elemento *prox;
}Elemento;
//função para criar a lista: retorna uma lista vazia
Elemento* criar_lista(void){
return NULL;
}
//Inserção no ínicio da lista
Elemento* inserir_no(Elemento* lista, int valor){
Elemento * no = (Elemento*)malloc(sizeof(Elemento));
no -> info = valor;
no -> prox = lista;
return no;
}
void imprimir_lista(Elemento *lista){
Elemento *p;//declarar ponteiro auxiliar p
for(p = lista; p != NULL; p = p -> prox){
printf("valor: %d\n", p->info);
}
}
int verificar_lista_vazia(Elemento *lista){
if(lista == NULL){
return 1;//retorna 1 se vazia e 0 senão
}else{
return 0;
}
}
int main(void){
Elemento* lista; //cria uma lista
lista = criar_lista(); //cria e inicializa como vazia
lista = inserir_no(lista,14);
lista = inserir_no(lista,16);
imprimir_lista(lista);
return 0;
}
```